# How to determine the size of DFT bins to implement a bandpass filter with FFTW on SDR

Tags: fft, dft, software-defined-radio

I'm implementing a bandpass filter to isolate the amplitude of a UHF FM signal with a 12.5Khz bandwidth. I'm having difficulty isolating the correct bins and bin spacing, given my DFT to isolate the signal such that neighbouring *channels* don't interfere.

My code is as follows:

```c
    int16_t* samples = (int16_t*)transfer->buffer;
    int numSamples = transfer->valid_length / sizeof(int16_t);
    fftw_complex* fftInput = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * numSamples);
    fftw_complex* fftOutput = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * numSamples);
    fftw_plan fftPlan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(numSamples, fftInput, fftOutput, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    for (int i = 0; i < numSamples; i++) {
      fftInput[i][0] = (double)samples[i];
      fftInput[i][1] = 0.0;
    }
    fftw_execute(fftPlan);
 
    double frequencyResolution = SAMPLE_RATE / (2.0 * (numSamples / 2));
    int startBin = round((lowerFrequency - 0.5 * frequencyResolution) / frequencyResolution);
    int endBin = round((upperFrequency + 0.5 * frequencyResolution) / frequencyResolution);

    double signalPower = 0.0;
    for (int i = startBin; i < endBin; i = i + 1) {
      double real = fftOutput[i][0];
      double imag = fftOutput[i][1];
      signalPower += (real * real) + (imag * imag);
    }

    signalPower /= (endBin - startBin + 1 );
    double signalPowerdBm = 10 * log10(signalPower);
    printf("val: %f\n", signalPowerdBm);
```

As it stands, my calculation of startBin and endBin is yielding values outside of the array indices; however, if I isolate these bins to values that yield high `signalPower` when I broadcast my signal (from a handheld radio), even with a very narrow endBin-startBin of 4 bins, I'm unable to isolate my signal and neighbouring channels register as signals on my desired centre frequency.

Sorry for the long question but:

- How do I determine the start and end indices for the DFT bins such to isolate a given bandwidth?
- If the center of the DFW is my center frequency on an SDR, what is the bandwidth? My sample rate is 2M and centre frequency is 476.650MHz for reference.